# Why the top navbar (offcanvas) not having perfect transition in my html css code

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a simple dashboard.

Here is the code:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<title>SC PayPortal</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;600;700;800&family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<!--fontawesome-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font/font/flaticon.css">
</head>
    
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  
  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <nav class="fixed-top align-top" id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
    <div class="simplebar-content" style="padding: 0px;"> <a class="sidebar-brand" href="#"> <span class="align-middle">ABC</span> </a>
      <ul class="navbar-nav align-self-stretch">
   
        <li class=""> <a class="nav-link text-left active"  role="button" 
          aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <i class="flaticon-bar-chart-1"></i> Dashboard </a> </li>
        <li class="has-sub"> <a class="nav-link collapsed text-left" href="#collapseExample2" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" > <i class="flaticon-user"></i> Profile </a>
          <div class="collapse menu mega-dropdown" id="collapseExample2">
            <div class="dropmenu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <div class="container-fluid ">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-12 px-2">
                    <div class="submenu-box">
                      <ul class="list-unstyled m-0">
                        <li><a href="">PHP Frameworks</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Laravel</a></li>
                        <li><a href=""> Codeigniter</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">Node.js</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class=""> <a class="nav-link text-left"  role="button" > <i class="flaticon-bar-chart-1"></i> setting </a> </li>
        <li class=""> <a class="nav-link text-left"  role="button" > <i class="flaticon-bar-chart-1"></i> invoice </a> </li>
        <li class=""> <a class="nav-link text-left"  role="button" > <i class="flaticon-bar-chart-1"></i> Bank </a> </li>
        <li class="sidebar-header"> tools and component </li>
        <li class=""> <a class="nav-link text-left"  role="button" > <i class="flaticon-bar-chart-1"></i> ui element </a> </li>
        <li class=""> <a class="nav-link text-left"  role="button" > <i class="flaticon-bar-chart-1"></i> form </a> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper --> 
  
  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div id="content">
      <div class="container-fluid p-0 px-lg-0 px-md-0"> 
        <!-- Topbar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light my-navbar"> 
          
          <!-- Sidebar Toggle (Topbar) -->
          <div type="button"  id="bar" class="nav-icon1 hamburger animated fadeInLeft" data-toggle="offcanvas"> <span></span> <span></span> <span></span> </div>
          
          <!-- Topbar Search -->
          <form class="d-none d-sm-inline-block form-inline navbar-search">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control bg-light " placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search">
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"> <i class="fas fa-search fa-sm"></i> </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
          
          <!-- Topbar Navbar -->
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            
            <!-- Nav Item - Search Dropdown (Visible Only XS) -->
            <li class="nav-item dropdown  d-sm-none"> 
              
              <!-- Dropdown - Messages -->
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right p-3">
                <form class="form-inline mr-auto w-100 navbar-search">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control bg-light border-0 small"
                    placeholder="Search for..." >
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"> <i class="fas fa-search fa-sm"></i> </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </li>
            
           
            
            <!-- Nav Item - User Information -->
            <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> <span class="mr-2 d-none d-lg-inline text-gray-600 small">ABC</span> <img class="img-profile rounded-circle" src="img/logo3.jpg" alt="profile-avt"> </a> </li>
          </ul>

        </nav>
        <!-- End of Topbar --> 
        
        <!-- Begin Page Content -->
 
   
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /#page-content-wrapper --> 
  
</div>
<!-- /#wrapper --> 

<!-- Optional JavaScript --> 
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS --> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" ></script> 
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script> 
<script>
 
$('#bar').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    $('#page-content-wrapper ,#sidebar-wrapper').toggleClass('toggled' );

});
  </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Part

```
body {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    background: #f7f7fc;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

a:hover{
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
}

body,
html { height: 100%;}





/*---------------------------------
sidebar
----------------------*/

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 100%;
    width:270px;
    left: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
   /*   background: #222e3c;*/
    background: #C9CACC;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    opacity: 0.7;
    
    border: solid 3px rgba(0,135,142,1.00);
}

#sidebar-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
    background: #222e3c;
}

#sidebar-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color:#989898;
    border-radius:10px;
}


.toggled#sidebar-wrapper {
    width:0px!important;
    height: 100%;
     left: -15px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar-brand {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.15rem;
    padding: 1.15rem 1.5rem;
    display: block;
    color: #f8f9fa;
}
.sidebar-header{
    text-transform:capitalize;
    padding: 1.5rem 1.5rem .375rem!important;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #ced4da;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a ,.submenu-box ul li a{
    color:gray!important;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-size: 14px;
      padding:10px 10px 10px 20px!important;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 400;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: .2px;
}

.submenu-box ul li a{
 padding:4px 10px 4px 20px!important;
  color:#c1c1c1!important;
}



.navbar-nav > li > a.active{
     color: #e9ecef!important;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg,rgba(59,125,221,.1),rgba(59,125,221,.0875) 50%,transparent);
    border-left:4px solid #3b7ddd;
}

.navbar-nav .has-sub > a.collapsed::after {
    transition: 0.4s ease;
}

.navbar-nav .has-sub > a.collapsed::after {
    color:gray;
    font-size: 10px;
    content: "\f078";
}
.navbar-nav .has-sub > a.collapsed::after {
   color:gray;
}

.navbar-nav .has-sub > a::after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 50%;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color:gray;
    display: block;
    content: "\f077";
    font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-top: -15px;
}

#wrapper{
    border: 3px solid rgba(82,172,0,1.00);
}

/*#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 200px;
}*/




.navbar-nav li{
  display:block!important;
  margin:2px 0px;
}


.nav-item .nav-link{
    display:block;
    color:white!important;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:6px 10px; 
    transition:0.4s ease;   
}

.navbar-nav > li > a i:before{
  margin:0px 5px 0px 0px;
  font-size:14px;
}


/*---------------------------------
sidebar
----------------------*/






/*---------------------------------
  main-content
----------------------*/

#page-content-wrapper {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    margin-left:270px;
    border:3px solid #E00D10;
    
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -270px;
    border: solid 15px rgba(188,164,0,1.00);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

 .toggled#page-content-wrapper{
     transition: all 0.5s ease;
     margin-left:0px;
     width: 100%;     
 }
 
 @media only screen and (min-width:992px){
 .toggled#page-content-wrapper{
    width:100%; 
    }
 }

/*---------------------------------
  main-content
----------------------*/



/*---------------------------------
cross-bar animation
----------------------*/


.nav-icon1{
  z-index: 999;
  position:relative;
  display: block;
  width:23px;
  margin:0px 30px 0px 25px;
   cursor:pointer;
  height: 25px;
}


.nav-icon1 span{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:3px;
  cursor:pointer;
  background-color:#5d5d5d;
  left:0;
  transform:rotate(0deg);
  transition:.30s ease-in-out;
}

.nav-icon1:hover span:nth-of-type(1){
  top:-3px
}

.nav-icon1:hover span:nth-of-type(3){
  top:19px;
}

.nav-icon1 span:nth-of-type(1){
   top:0;
}

.nav-icon1 span:nth-of-type(2){
   top:8px;
}

.nav-icon1 span:nth-of-type(3){
   top:16px;
}

/*.nav-icon1.open span:nth-of-type(1){
   top:8px;
   transform:rotate(135deg);
}

.nav-icon1.open span:nth-of-type(2){
   top:8px;
   opacity:0;
   left:-30px;
}

.nav-icon1.open span:nth-of-type(3){
   top:8px;
   transform:rotate(-135deg);
}
*/

/*---------------------------------
cross-bar animation
----------------------*/



/*---------------------------------
header navbar design
----------------------*/
.my-navbar{
  padding:0px;
  background-color:white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.16);
}

.text-gray-600 {
    color: #858796!important;
}
.nav-link .img-profile {
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a >i{
    font-size: 18px;
    color:#b3b3b3;
    margin:8px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.badge-counter {
    position: absolute;
    transform:scale(.7);
    transform-origin: top right;
    right:6px;
    margin-top:4px;
}


.dropdown, .dropleft, .dropright, .dropup {
    position: relative;
}

.nav-flag, .nav-icon {
    padding: .1rem .8rem;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #6c757d;
    transition: background .1s ease-in-out,color .1s ease-in-out;
    line-height: 1.4;
}


.navbar-expand .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
}
.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    box-shadow: 0 0.1rem 0.2rem rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
}
.dropdown-menu-lg {
    min-width: 20rem;
}


.position-relative {
    position: relative!important;
}

.nav-item .indicator {
    background: #3b7ddd;
    box-shadow: 0 0.1rem 0.2rem rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    padding: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -8px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: top .1s ease-out;
    font-size: .675rem;
    color: #fff;
}

/*---------------------------------
 header navbar design
----------------------*/
```

The problem that i am getting is :
When i toggle and let sidenav bar hide so the page-content occupy 100% space.But while doing that the Top Navbar has a avtar (circular) which first goes complete right than sticks at right end.
That transition isn't look properly.

https://codepen.io/ajaxx1019/pen/OJXpmpW

How do I rectify that ?
Please help

Comment: Yeah I can reproduce your bug. Let me check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you set the width of your page-content-wrapper element to 100%. Because the width can't be animated from 'auto' to 100%, it just jumps to 100% without animation. You can remove this part because the container-fluid class sets the width to 100% and the flex element within this container takes the available space.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/frednijs/pen/xxOqdaK

Remove width:100% in the below parts and it should work as you want.

```
 .toggled#page-content-wrapper {
   transition: all 0.5s ease;
   margin-left:0px;
   width: 100%;   
 }

@media only screen and (min-width:992px) {
   .toggled#page-content-wrapper {
     width:100%; 
   }
}
```